# How to display a dropdown list item inside an input search box with react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to display a dropdown list item inside the search box using react-hooks.
I have tried using the useState hook to display the item but it didn't work.
I do not have any errors in the console.

Please Help.

[Codesandbox project link](https://codesandbox.io/s/windbnb-hft2i?file=/src/components/Header/LocationDropdown/LocationDropdown.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here: [Codesandbox Fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/windbnb-forked-83j4n?file=/src/components/Header/LocationDropdown/LocationDropdown.js)

If you want to share state between components it should either be declared in the highest one in the hierarchy and passing it down as a prop, or by using a monolithic state management library like Redux.

Comment: Can it be done with react context as well?

Comment: Indeed.  React's createContext can be used rather than Redux.  For a comparison see especially the conclusion in this article: https://dev.to/ayushmanbthakur/redux-vs-context-api-3182#:~:text=In%20React%20there%20are%20mainly,level%20state%20management%20in%20React.